# How can i add my app in share app list for image?

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to show my app when user try to share Image from Photo gallery. How can i show my app in that list?

I tried with public.image as content type but not working for me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a share extension for your application. For detailed info you can check the official apple documentation for extensions https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/index.html

Comment: Thanks for Answer, If i want share Open in feature from Photo gallery, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **UIActivity​View​Controller** to share the images and data. 
If you want to see tutorial please refer following link.
[UIActivity​View​Controller](http://nshipster.com/uiactivityviewcontroller/)

Comment: I want this from photo gallery of iPhone native app